# Why checkbox checked only for the current page I am on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I implement table with paging.

Here the code to create table:

```
<table id="ContactsTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.CheckBox("chkBoxAllEmails", new { onclick = "SelectAllEmails(this);" })
            </th>
            <th>
                First Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Last Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (UserContact item in ViewBag.Contacts)
    { 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id = "@(("chkbox" + index++).ToString())"  name="chboxEmail"     type="checkbox"  value = "@item.email" onclick="SelectEmail(this); " />
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.firstName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.lastName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.email
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Here is the code that create paging in the table:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ContactsTable').dataTable();
        });
    </script>
```

And here is how this table looks:

[image]

As you can see table contain checkbox column. When I check the header of the checkbox column 
all the checkbox have to be selected.Here is the JS code that implements it:

```
    function SelectAllEmails(chboxSelectAllElements) {

        var chboxEmailsArray = document.getElementsByName("chboxEmail");        
        if (chboxSelectAllElements.checked) {

            for (var i = 0; i < chboxEmailsArray.length; i++) {
                chboxEmailsArray[i].checked = true;
            }
        }

        else {

            for (var i = 0; i < chboxEmailsArray.length; i++) {
                chboxEmailsArray[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is how it's looks after I check the header of the checkbox:

[image]

But when I select second page in paging, turn out that the checkboxes not checked:

[image]

i.e checkboxes will only work on current pagination page.

My question is why not all checkboxes selected?
I need to check or uncheck all checkboxes when the checkbox in the header checked or unchecked , any idea or examples how  can I implement it in my example?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use on :

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="chboxEmail"]', function(e) {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Than use the .on() method to delegate the click event to future elements added to the DOM

Comment: Hamidreza,please can you provide more detailed example?